# Nginx Ingress paths to redirect to multiple services in azure K8's

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I'm using azure k8's at the moment. I have two services which i need to expose via same domain and wanted add paths for different service.

ingress files as follows

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  namespace : {{ .Values.namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.kibana.ingressdomain }}
    secretName: abb-aks-cert
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.kibana.ingressdomain }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app/kibana
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-service
          servicePort: 5601
      - path: /grafana
        backend:
            serviceName: monitor-grafana
            servicePort: 80
```

When i define like this i'm getting 404 errors. Is there any solution for this?

Kubernetes version is 1.16

Answer (score 1):

This is very common mistake people make.
Web applications usually (by default) serve with base path = `/`.
During first request, the website resonds correctly but with incorrect paths because it not aware that its running behind proxy and that sth is rewriting the paths.

You need to set root/base path for both appications accordingly and remove the rewrite because its not needed.

---

For kibana you need to set:

> #### server.basePath:
>
> Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy. Use the server.rewriteBasePath setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup. This setting cannot end in a slash (/).

More in [kibana docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html)

---

For grafana you need to set:

> #### root_url
>
> This is the full URL used to access Grafana from a web browser. This is important if you use Google or GitHub OAuth authentication (for the callback URL to be correct).
>
> > Note: This setting is also important if you have a reverse proxy in front of Grafana that exposes it through a subpath. In that case add the subpath to the end of this URL setting.
>
> #### serve_from_sub_path
>
> Serve Grafana from subpath specified in root_url setting. By default it is set to false for compatibility reasons.
>
> By enabling this setting and using a subpath in root_url above, e.g. root_url = http://localhost:3000/grafana, Grafana is accessible on http://localhost:3000/grafana

More in [grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#root_url)